# TYPO3 tx_news: How to remove “news” prefix from RealURL path

Tags: typo3, realurl, tx-news

I  have a problem. Does anybody know how to get rid of the news prefix from url ?

it is like this

```
http://www.example.com/**news**/detail/title-of-news/
```

and I would like to be like this

```
http://www.example.com/detail/title-of-news/
```

Or replace news word with diffrent "article" for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. place single view plugin on separate `article` page
2. Use `fixedPostVars` (from RealURL docs) to shorten the url, [read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9622760/1066240) to see the sample for `tt_news` (sorry I haven't now any sample for News + RU, but there's no problem with tuning this):

Sample:

```
'fixedPostVars' => array(
    '123' =>array(
        array(
            'GETvar' => 'tx_ttnews[tt_news]',
            'lookUpTable' => array(
                'table' => 'tt_news',
                'id_field' => 'uid',
                'alias_field' => 'title',
                'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                'useUniqueCache' => 1,
                'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                    'strtolower' => 1,
                    'spaceCharacter' => '-',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. 
[link](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/Main/Administration/Realurl/Index.html)

here is template for tx_news. All I have to do is change line:
`'70' => 'newsDetailConfiguration',`
to the pid with single news view.
Tnak you once again.